# Angular error handling on a promise

Tags: angularjs, exception, promise

I'm new to Angular and the general idea of promises so please bear with me on this one.

I have this general setup for a promise below:

```
ApiService.getDataUriForUrl(imageUrl).then(function(url){
    requests--;
}, function(error){
    console.log('oh no!');
});
```

I wrote this thinking that the `function(error)` would catch exceptions thrown on the `getDataUriForUrl()` call, but I now am led to believe it is for dealing with errors in the `then(...` area.

How should I be formatting this to intercept errors as I desire? (catching exceptions thrown in the getDataUriForUrl() call).

Comment: The syntax you have is correct but to be clear it won't catch exceptions in getDataUriForUrl, it instead catches failures. Meaning you have to explicitly call $q.reject inside getDataUriForUrl.

so think of success and failure in promises as handlers for .resolve and .reject. The creator of the service or api has to invoke one those functions.

Edit : A simple fix would be to catch errors inside the service and simply call $q.reject

Comment: Alright thank you very much, this helped me solve the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The errors thrown in the onFulfill callback will not be passed to the onReject callback.
Instead you can pass the first callback to then method and call the then method aging on the return.

```
ApiService.getDataUriForUrl(imageUrl).then(function(url){
    requests--;
    return new Error ();// you can't throw it
}).then(null, function(error){
    console.log('oh no!');// I can catch error from the getData or the onFulfill callback
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calling $q.reject or $q.resolve for every api method you can just write a interceptor for response and responseError. In which you can just $q.reject() or $q.resolve(). 
This would be cleaner and modularized.

Sample code:

```
(function (global) {
    "use strict";

    angular.module("TestAPp").factory('httpInterceptor', ["$rootScope", "$q", function ($rootScope, $q) {
        return {
            response:function(response){
                return response;
            },
            responseError: function (response) {
                return $q.reject(response);
            }
        };
    }]);

}(this));
```

//registering interceprtor

```
(function (global) {
    "use strict";

    angular.module("TestApp", [])
           .config([ '$httpProvider',function ($httpProvider) {
                /* Register the interceptor */
                $httpProvider.interceptors.push('httpInterceptor');

    }]);

}(this));
```

You can refer to [Error Handling in angular](http://mysoftwareexperience.blogspot.in/2016/02/error-handling-and-authentication-with.html) for more info.